# Formula to SUM values that are flagged

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, worksheet-function, sumifs

Basically, I wish to only sum up values in one column when that row is marked or flagged. eg:

```
Flag|Value
1   |14
    |23
1   |3
1   |7
```

So the formula will return `24`.

I can easily achieve this if I dedicate each row with an extra column to display value if there is a flag. Then SUM that extra column to get the total.
However, I do not wish to dedicate another column to extract values in each row.

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you considered using the `SumIfs` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doable with just SUMIF, of more general availability:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,1,B:B)
```